# columnDefinition="DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE", don't work

Tags: java, jpa

I am using this code:

```
@Column(name = "FECHA_CREACION_TIMESTAMP",columnDefinition="DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE", insertable=false)
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date fechaCreacionTimestamp;
```

But when I insert some data to the table, it doesn't have the date just have the date like null.

Comment: Is `DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE` valid SQL? `columnDefinition` [expects an SQL fragment](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Column.html#columnDefinition()).

Comment: Show us your `INSERT` statement. In order for the default to "kick in", you must not specify that column in the column list.

Comment: i have the following method to insert in the table: public void insertarDatos(){
        PruebasFechas pruebas=new PruebasFechas();
        pruebas.setPruebaId(new BigDecimal(1));
        getFacade().create(pruebas);        
    }

Comment: Is the solution mentioned in the answer not working?

Answer (score 2):

**Updated Answer: (Now that I know that you are using Oracle)**

What you need is to make sure that the column doesn't get included in the insert statements. For that, you need to update your `@Column` annoation like:

```
@Column(..other properties.., insertable = false)
```

See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/) for more details.

Now, you also need to make sure that the generated value is available in your domain object after you perform the `insert`. If you are using Hibernate, and do not mind using Hibernate annotations, you can put the following annotation on your field.

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.Generated(org.hibernate.annotations.GenerationTime.INSERT)
```

Hibernate will automatically perform the required `select` query for you.

If you are not using Hibernate, you will need to do a `select` yourself to fetch the generated value after performing the `insert`. `JPA` doesn't have anything to specify that this should be done automatically.

Comment: MySQL does not have a function named `SYSDATE` - Oracle does.

Comment: It does. [check this out](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sysdate)

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like :

```
@Column(name = "FECHA_CREACION_TIMESTAMP",columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP", insertable=false)
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date fechaCreacionTimestamp;
```